# Which web.config file should contain the following values?

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I have searched for a straightforward answer as to which MVC project/View web.config file
should contain the following values:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

I am currently doing this on Vista SP1 using VS 2010 Express. SQL ServerCE 4.0 is also installed.
Can someone give me some details on what goes where?

Thanks in advance . . .
TomJ

Answer (score 0):

That would go to under `<configuration><configSections>` in your web.config. Here is an [example](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-5K1xVWSdyUA/TWnZawn0FII/AAAAAAAAALw/X0znM-5KxCQ/s1600/webconfig.png).

Comment: Thanks ** BluesRockAddict **, this indeed helps